# Angular 2 Page / Component not reloading

Tags: javascript, angular

Using the Nav on the website and going from

http://localhost:4200/mens

to

http://localhost:4200/mens/shirts

Works fine but when clicking on another category from with shirts like Hats the component/page doesn't reload and i'm unsure why as i'm not getting a error and it work fine when you click in the first category but within that category if you click on another it doesn't.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path : '',
        component: WebsiteComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path : '',
                component: HomePageComponent,
            },
            {
                path : 'mens',
                component: MensPageComponent
            },
            {
                path : 'mens/:category',
                component: MensPageComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})], Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting your params in the men's component?

Here is a stackblitz that works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buahdy

It uses route.params observable that emits when the route changes, if you are using a snapshot it will not change as it is not an observable.

```
category$ = this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params.category));

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

and in the template show the category with the async pipe

```
Category {{ category$ | async }}
```

When you go from mens/shoes to mens/shirts the men's component does not reload, only the category param has changed. Subscribing to the param with route.params is how you trigger an update in your component.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `children` property in the route. The component will need a `router-outlet` for those `children` routes to be rendered.

`WebsiteComponent` template:

```html
<!-- some code -->

<!-- where children routes are rendered -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: The site renders fine. i don't have a render issue the issue is reloading the component/page after it has been loaded one already

Comment: There is not a issue with MensPageComponent the issue is that the router is not allow the page to load again if it already been loaded with the same url.

So if you load http://localhost:4200/mens/shirts it will load because it see it as a new route but if you try and change from shirts to hats or jumpers it will not load because it thinks the page is already loaded. i'm not talking about changing the URL in the URL bar because that would work i mean changing page by using  [routerLink]=

Comment: I've tried imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})], but that don't work

Comment: It may be related to the way you read the parameter. If you can put the code for that component it will be helpful.